# Intermittent syntax error in a bash script involving echo, a python script, grep, sed, bc, and date

Tags: python, bash, date, sed, bc

I have written a python script to take magnetic field measurements from a Raspberry Pi Astro "Sense Hat" sensor. It is called "mag-AstroPi.py":

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
from sense_hat import SenseHat
sense = SenseHat()
raw = sense.get_compass_raw()
#print(x: {x}, y: {y}, z: {z}.format(**raw))
#alternatives
print(sense.compass_raw)
```

This is the script provided by element14, the manufacturer of the Sense Hat.

The script outputs magnetic field data in three axes (X, Y, and Z) in microteslas, along with a bunch of extra characters:

> pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python mag-AstroPi.py
>
> {'y': 13.895279884338379, 'x': -1.1642401218414307, 'z': -0.4132799804210663}

I need to remove the extra characters, multiply the values by 1,000 in order to convert them into nanoteslas (standard SI unit for my particular application), and then log the multiplied value alongside the date and time into a file. This needs to happen every two seconds.

I want there to be three separate log files - one for the X axis, one for the Y axis, and one for the Z axis. However, for now, I am just working with the Y-axis data. Once I get the Y-axis data logging working, I can then duplicate and alter for the two other axes.

So I wrote a bash script, AstroPiMagLogger.sh, which runs at boot via a cron job:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
        echo $(python mag-AstroPi.py -n | grep "y" | cut -d " " -f2 | cut -c 1-18 | sed 's/$/*1000/' | bc; date +"%Y,%m,%d,%T,%Z") >> rawysecnT.txt
        sleep 2
done
```

This *should* extract the Y-axis value only, multiply it by 1,000, and then save it alongside the current date, time, and time zone into a new text file, rawysecnT.txt.

It works, sorta... here are the contents of rawysecnT.txt:

> 13703.761100769043000 2015,09,14,08:56:41,UTC
>
> 13703.761100769043000 2015,09,14,08:56:44,UTC
>
> 13613.041877746582000 2015,09,14,08:56:46,UTC
>
> 13794.480323791504000 2015,09,14,08:56:49,UTC
>
> 13804.560661315918000 2015,09,14,08:56:52,UTC
>
> 13875.120162963867000 2015,09,14,08:56:55,UTC
>
> 13633.201599121094000 2015,09,14,08:56:58,UTC
>
> 2015,09,14,08:57:00,UTC
>
> 2015,09,14,08:57:03,UTC
>
> 13744.080543518066000 2015,09,14,08:57:06,UTC
>
> 14016.241073608398000 2015,09,14,08:57:09,UTC

As you can see, it works most of the time. But every now and then, it doesn't log the magnetic field measurement to the file; it only logs the date and time.

Earlier today, I had the logging working perfectly, but that was before I added the code to multiply the magnetic data by 1000 (i.e. earlier today, the script was only logging the original magnetic data in microteslas, along with the date/time). I have several hours worth of data like that without any errors at all, so it's apparent I've stuffed something up when adding in the code for multiplication of the magnetic measurement.

I decided to run the following directly in the command line (rather than through the script), in order to debug.

> echo $(python mag-AstroPi.py -n |grep "y" | cut -d " " -f2 | cut -c 1-18 | sed 's/$/*1000/' | bc; date +"%Y,%m,%d,%T,%Z")

Predictably, this worked about a dozen times, with the following output printed to the terminal, which is exactly how I want it:

> 14167.440414428711000 2015,09,14,09:07:30,UTC

and then, one last time, it returned the following error:

> (standard_in) 1: syntax error
>
> 2015,09,14,09:07:59,UTC

Given that the error is intermittent, and I'm fairly new to programming (I've only been at it about a month), I've got no idea what could possibly be the issue.

I would appreciate any thoughts anyone may have as to why this is working most of the time but not all of the time.

---

The two sample outputs requested in the comments are as follows:

```bash
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python mag-AstroPi.py -n | grep "y" | cut -d " " -f2 | cut -c 1-18 | sed 's/$/*1000/' | bc; date +"%Y,%m,%d,%T,%Z" 
14076.720237731934000 2015,09,14,09:53:33,UTC 

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python mag-AstroPi.py -n 
{'y': 13.935601234436035, 'x': -1.506960153579712, 'z': 0.24192002415657043}
```

Comment: Have you considered adding a few lines of python to manipulate your output, rather than using a long pipeline? Personally, that's how I'd go about it.

Comment: Hi, @TomFenech, thanks for your comment. Pretty much the only Python I know is what is in my OP, and I only know that because it was supplied by someone else (I didn't write it myself, and don't really understand it either). Could you please point me in the direction of any tutorials that would explain how to do this in Python? Thanks. :)

Comment: I think that the first thing you need to do is identify what each of the steps are doing (or what they're _supposed_ to be doing at least). If you're stuck with something specific, it would be better to focus your question on that (assuming that you can't find out for yourself). A general request to be pointed in the right direction isn't really a good fit for this site I'm afraid.

Comment: No worries, thanks. :) I shall research Python further. In any case, it doesn't explain why the above bash script doesn't work though... :/

Comment: The [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) is quite good, although it's not aimed at raw beginners, some programming competence is assumed.

Comment: In order for us to work out why your current script isn't working, we'd need to see some output from `python mag-AstroPi.py -n` and the corresponding output from `python mag-AstroPi.py -n | grep "y" | cut -d " " -f2 | cut -c 1-18 | sed 's/$/*1000/' | bc; date +"%Y,%m,%d,%T,%Z"`.

Comment: You should log the original data in a file and do your processing on it. This way you could give us the original lines corresponding to the unexpected outputs. This could help.

Comment: @PM2Ring, thanks for that link. I'll give it a look over. :)

Comment: @TomFenech, the two sample outputs you requested are as follows:
> pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python mag-AstroPi.py -n | grep "y" | cut -d " " -f2 | cut -c 1-18 | sed 's/$/*1000/' | bc; date +"%Y,%m,%d,%T,%Z"

> 14076.720237731934000

> 2015,09,14,09:53:33,UTC

> pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python mag-AstroPi.py -n

> {'y': 13.935601234436035, 'x': -1.506960153579712, 'z': 0.24192002415657043}

Thanks in advance for your thoughts. :)

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, I can't do that as I need to log the date and time at the moment the measurement is taken, not when the measurement is multiplied... or is there some way of taking the date and time from the original file and inserting it into the new file (with the multiplied measurements)?

Comment: FWIW, your Python script is retrieving the magnetic field data twice. First with `sense.get_compass_raw()`, and then again with `sense.compass_raw`. So you should probably comment out the `raw = sense.get_compass_raw()` line.

Comment: The efficient way to do what you want is to do it all in a Python script, rather than using this combination of tools you're currently using. Python can easily do the arithmetic on the data, get the current time & date, and format those things exactly how you want. And it can also do the time delay.

Comment: For interested readers, here's a link to the [Sense HAT API](http://pythonhosted.org/sense-hat/api/).

Comment: @TomFenech, I spent ages trying to figure out how to edit that comment. By the time I figured it out, it said "can't edit comments after five minutes".

So here it is again, hopefully formatted correctly...

@TomFenech, the two sample outputs you requested are as follows:

`pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python mag-AstroPi.py -n | grep "y" | cut -d " " -f2 | cut -c 1-18 | sed 's/$/*1000/' | bc; date +"%Y,%m,%d,%T,%Z"`

`14076.720237731934000`

`2015,09,14,09:53:33,UTC`

`pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python mag-AstroPi.py -n`

`{'y': 13.935601234436035, 'x': -1.506960153579712, 'z': 0.24192002415657043}`


Thanks :)

Comment: I meant [edit] your **question**! The link in my previous comment (and this one) allow you to do that. Comments shouldn't be used to add detail to your question.

Comment: Thanks for those points, @PM2Ring. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously I can't test this code properly without a Sense Hat sensor, but you should find it helpful. It does an infinite loop, so you need to send it a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to kill it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
from sense_hat import SenseHat

sense = SenseHat()

#Un-comment the following line to ensure the compass is on and the gyro & accelerometer are off
#sense.set_imu_config(True, False, False)

while True:
    raw_field = sense.get_compass_raw()
    now = time.strftime("%Y,%m,%d,%X,%Z")
    print(raw_field['y'] * 1000, now)
    time.sleep(2)
```

If you're using Python 2 you'll need to remove the parentheses in the `print` line, or add `from __future__ import print_function` before the other `import` lines.

It's not hard to adapt this code to write directly to a named file rather than having to pipe its output. But I'll leave that as an Exercise for the Reader. :) And it's also easy to modify it write to 3 files for x, y, and z.

---

I *suspect* that sometimes the SenseHat simply doesn't return the expected magnetic field data, but it's hard to tell from the info you posted what it *does* return when it does that. It possibly returns a dictionary containing empty data values, or it could return a totally empty dictionary.

So if you still get bad output, let me know what it looks like & any associated error message, and I should be able to show you how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, @PM2Ring, that works perfectly. I didn't expect you to provide the code but I appreciate it immensely.

I actually re-ran my original python script and that is the cause of the intermittent fault. Every now and then, this comes up (but not always):

(will include error in next comment due to comment length restrictions)

Comment: sudo python mag-AstroPi.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mag-AstroPi.py", line 4, in <module>
    raw = sense.get_compass_raw()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 761, in get_compass_raw
    raw = self._get_raw_data('compassValid', 'compass')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 688, in _get_raw_data
    if self._read_imu():

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 669, in _read_imu
    self._init_imu()  # Ensure imu is initialised
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 633, in _init_imu
    raise OSError('IMU Init Failed, please run as root / use sudo')
OSError: IMU Init Failed, please run as root / use sudo

Comment: God only knows what that error means, and to be honest at this point it's way beyond me. I'll look at the Python tutorial you linked to earlier and do some more learning in general and will attempt to decipher that error message for myself at some stage. :)

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @ZPMMaker: The Python error messages aren't too bad once you get used to them. But they're not easy to read in comments! So it would be better to append them to your question (in a code block to preserve formatting). You may be able get rid of that error by properly initialising the IMU sensor. So un-comment that `sense.set_imu_config` line in my script & see if that helps.

Comment: Most of the Python traceback is just reporting where the error was detected (that `raise` line). The script contains a guess for why the error was detected (permission denied for an i2c bus?), but it may just be obscuring the real cause. You can use `try` to capture exceptions like these in case you want your script to retry or just ignore the failure.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're trying to do could (and almost certainly should) be done within the Python script itself. `get_compass_raw()` is returning you a dictionary, so you can extract the `y` value (and multiply by 1000) directly:

```
raw = sense.get_compass_raw()
y_component_nT = raw['y'] * 1000
```

To add your timestamp, I'd use the built-in `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
```

You can then format the time however you want, using `now.strftime(format)`, where `format` is a format string built up as shown in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

I'll leave the challenges of writing to a file in python and pausing execution to you - they're already covered in many good answers on this site and elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for that code, @TomFenech. That works well. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is better done in the Python script itself, and if you're unfamiliar with Python, this is a good opportunity to learn some small parts of it. As for your pipeline, I think the key issue is in `cut -c 1-18 | sed 's/$/*1000/' | bc`. The floating point numbers are not guaranteed to be a specific width or even format since you just printed a dictionary without requesting any formatting, so sometimes this will include the comma (or final brace for the last component), or be in scientific notation such as `2.34e-07`. bc does not understand those forms. Also, as the script only prints the one line with all values, grep does nothing.

If I were to use a pipeline like this to extract a value, I would probably use something like `sed -e "s/.*'y': \([-Ee.0-9]*\).*/\1/" -e "s/[Ee]\(.*\)/*10^\1/"` instead of the cuts (the latter substitution converts e forms to bc compatible expressions). On top of that, bc has some specific rules regarding precision, which mean the exponent handling requires you to set `scale` or everything becomes zero.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, @YannVernier. Makes sense to me. However I will end up going with PM2Ring's posted solution (which does everything in Python). And I'll certainly be learning more about Python; it was something I was intending to do, but I was hoping to be able to leave it for a month or so and just try to really master bash first. All good. Thanks again everyone for your help. :)